# Login View controller before SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform, swrevealviewcontroller

I followed parse.com tutorials on how to implement login + register + segue to main controller if registration or login is successful. This works beautiful.

I then wanted to implement a side navigation using SWRevealViewController. I followed APPCODA link on this and got it working only when "SWRevealViewController" is the initial view controller.

When i have my parse login controller as initial i can't see anything from the navigational controller aka "SWRevealViewController."

how would i be able fix this, make my login/register controllers the initial controllers and still be able to have SWRevealViewController when login/register is successful?

i would appreciate any help or pointers.

below is my APPDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

LoginView *lv = [[LoginView alloc]init];

SidebarViewController *sbvc = [[SidebarViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:lv];
UINavigationController *menuVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:sbvc];

SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:menuVC frontViewController:nav];
revealController.delegate = self;

self.menu = revealController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.menu;


[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"XXXXXXXXXX"];

[Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              clientKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"];

[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];



  return YES;
    }
```

Comment: When I have to do something similar to this in my app (basically, replacing the entire navigation stack one signup/login is finished), I start with a `UINavigationController` and (when signup/login is finished), I push to my root `UIViewController` and (in that controller's `viewDidAppear:`) then replace the `viewControllers` stack for the `UINavigationController` without animation. If that sounds like what you're looking for, I can post my code as an answer.

Comment: Let me take a look and see how i can implement in mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In apps with user sessions, it is usually best to keep login/signup on a separate view hierarchy from the rest of the app and present the internal structure if there is an active session. You can achieve this by checking for

```
[PFUser currentUser]
```

as it will return `nil` if the user is not logged in.

**Provide a check in your AppDelegate like so:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // .. Rest of your initialization code

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {

        // Let's pop them right to the home screen
        [self showHomeScreen];
    }
    else {

        // Present login vc
        LoginView *lv = [[LoginView alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lv];
        self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)showHomeScreen {

    SidebarViewController *sbvc = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *menuVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sbvc];

    UIViewController *home = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] initWithRearViewController:menuVC frontViewController:nav];

    self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
}
```

Then, by including

```
- (void)showHomeScreen;
```

in `AppDelegate.h`, you can call this method upon successful registration/login:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate showHomeScreen];
```

Comment: TNX Alex, But that didn't work for me. I got a whole bunch of errors when i tried the format above. could i be doing something wrong in story board?

Comment: Ah ok, I see now where you had said 'segue' and did not realize you were using storyboards. Your answer you've described below should work. SWRevealController acts as a container, housing a front and rear view controller

Comment: I now get the issue where is the PFUser is signed in, it doesn't initiate that session when the app is closed. do i need to add the [PFUser currentUser]; method to SWreveal?

Comment: After running [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground...] and getting a success, NSLog(@"%@", [PFUser currentUser]); to see if you get something back other than (null). If your currentUser is set, this should maintain it's state even after closing the app and re-opening

Comment: Alternatively to what I had suggested in showHomeScreen, you could push to SWReveal directly from the success block in loginWithUsernameInBackground right from LoginView. Then add the AppDelegate currentUser check in LoginView's viewDidLoad

Comment: @AlexK This is what I do in my `AppDelegate`, but I think the OP was asking about **swapping** the UI, not conditional loading of the initial UI.

Comment: @mbm29414 if that is the case, could the OP start with an SWReveal containing Login as the front, and use `[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:vc animated:YES];` with the desired ViewController to replace, as needed?

Comment: @AlexK I think the `SWReveal` is for side menus, so I don't think it's made for what you're describing. I **think** his discussion of the `SWReveal` is a red herring for his main need, which is a way to "fix" the UI stack after logging in a user, when the Login `UIViewController` is the root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

i just find out how to display my dashboard view from app delegate programmatically. Using SWRevealViewController & swift 2.0:

on your main.storyboard, you will have to identify the menu views (I meant not the navigation controllers)

for my right hand side menu, identity inspector->identiy->storyboardID = 'right2'.

for my left hand side menu, called it 'rear2'.

for my front view, on the navigation View controller that presents my dashboard view, i set the identity to 'dashboard'

In your appdelegate, under my function 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions':

```
//this is your main.storyboard
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

//initialize your FRONT view controller, ie my dashboard view, mine   is a UINavigationController, which then presents a table view , ie why i instantiate with a UINavigationController.

let frontviewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashboard") as? UINavigationController


//initialize REAR View Controller- it is the LEFT hand menu. 

let rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rear2") as? UITableViewController

//initialize RIGHT View Controller - it is your RIGHT hand menu.

let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("right2") as? UITableViewController

let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

mainRevealController.frontViewController = frontviewcontroller
mainRevealController.rightViewController = rightViewController
mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController

self.window!.rootViewController = mainRevealController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

hope it helps someone else.
Thank you
D.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I swap out my navigation hierarchy after a user logins in:

## UINavigationController Version

```
+ (void)postSignInUICodeFromViewController:(UIViewController *)vc {
    // Log in was successful

    // Create new view controller
    ViewController1 *v1             = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];

    typeof(vc) weakVc               = vc;
    // This is a property that I have added to my
    // custom UIViewController subclass. As you might
    // guess, it's called in "viewDidAppear:"
    v1.viewDidAppearCompletionBlock = ^{
        // After pushing the new UI hierarchy into view,
        // this will delete/remove the rest of the UI stack
        weakVc.navigationController.viewControllers = @[v1];
    };
    // At this point (since the block above hasn't yet fired),
    // you're pushing your new UI hierarchy ON TOP OF the login
    // view controller
    [vc.navigationController pushViewController:v1 animated:YES];
}
```

## UITabBarController Version

```
+ (void)postSignInUICodeFromViewController:(UIViewController *)vc {
    // Log in was successful

    // Create new UI hierarchy
    ViewController1 *v1             = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
    NavViewController *nav1         = [[UINavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v1];
    ViewController1 *v2             = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    NavViewController *nav2         = [[UINavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v2];
    ViewController1 *v3             = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
    NavViewController *nav3         = [[UINavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v3];
    ViewController1 *v4             = [[ViewController4 alloc] init];
    NavViewController *nav4         = [[UINavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v4];

    TabBarViewController *tabBar    = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
    tabBar.viewControllers          = @[nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4];

    typeof(vc) weakVc               = vc;
    typeof(tabBar) weakTabBar       = tabBar;
    __weak NavViewController *navVc = (NavViewController *)weakVc.navigationController;
    // This is a property that I have added to my
    // custom UITabBarController subclass. As you might
    // guess, it's called in "viewDidAppear:"
    tabBar.viewDidAppearCompletionBlock = ^{
        // After pushing the new UI hierarchy into view,
        // this will delete/remove the rest of the UI stack
        weakVc.navigationController.viewControllers = @[weakTabBar];
    };
    // At this point (since the block above hasn't yet fired),
    // you're pushing your new UI hierarchy ON TOP OF the login
    // view controller
    [vc.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
}
```

In both examples, I made up a new class named `ViewController1`. In the `UITabBarController` example, all the rest are also made up class names for purposes of illustration only. **You would need to put in your class names instead.**

Comment: Would you be able to explain your code? do i have to change the names of the view controllers to match mine? what if there isn't any tab bars in my app? tnx

Comment: @MiguelBonilla I re-wrote a new example for simply pushing a view controller instead of my (somewhat) complicated situation of needing a `UITabBarController`. I hope that helps. Out of curiosity, why are you still asking for code updates when you've accepted an answer?

Comment: I accepted the answer because it gave me an idea and clarified it for me. It didn't necessarily worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

OK, SO i figured it out. here it goes;

Instead of creating a segue to the main view controller, create it to the SWRevealViewController. I figured that SW has that controller set as "sw_front." This will only work if you have it as a segue through the PFUser.

Answer (score 0):

In your **login ViewController** create button Action.

You can set like this.

```
  @IBAction func btnLoginAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let objAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rearViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "backTableVc") as? backTableVc
    let frontViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController
    let naviRoot = UINavigationController(rootViewController: frontViewController!)
    naviRoot.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    let mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()
    mainRevealController.frontViewController = naviRoot
    mainRevealController.rearViewController = rearViewController

    UIView.transition(from: (objAppDelegate.window?.rootViewController!.view)!, to: mainRevealController.view, duration: 0.6, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: {
        _ in
        objAppDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
    })
    objAppDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```