# SWRevealViewController after a login view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app that have a login view and then after the login is successes I want to have a view with a side menu.
I am using `SWRevealViewController` to make the slide menu.
But the problem as I said is the login view will be the first view not the `SWRevealViewController`.
I tried to do the following inside prepareForSegue method.

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController;
[revealViewController initWithRearViewController: [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuTableViewCell"]frontViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"]];
```

this is not working. That's the only code I have inside prepareForSegue method, I deleted the if statement because I only have one segue inside the loginview so I figured I don't need the IF.
Should I delete the `SWRevealViewController` from the storyboard? or make the segue from the login view to `SWRevealViewController`
I don't know what to do.
There's no explanation for situation for using `SWRevealViewController` inside the views not the first view.
I am building this app for iOS for objective c for iPhone.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try this It's working for me. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959896/4845562)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do your storyboard hierarchy like this.

- Drag a **ViewController** and change a class to **SWRevealViewController.**
- Drag a **ViewController** Embedded in **NavigationController**. Change class name to **LoginViewController**.
- Change your **NavigationController's** storyboard ID to **"LoginNavigationController".**
- Assign new custom segue named **sw_front** from SWRevealViewController to NavigationController and change class of segue to **SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.**
- Drag a controller having **TableView** as a subView which is your **MenuViewController** for Sidebar.
- Assign new custom segue named **sw_rear** from SWRevealViewController to MenuViewController and change class of segue to **SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.**
- Now drag a ViewController named **HomeViewController** embedded in **NavigationController** and assign a custom segue with identifier "**Home**" and class with **SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController.**
- Change storyboard ID of NavigationController to **"HomeNavigationController".**

This should be the setup in your storyboard.

[image: Storyboard structure]

Now here is the coding part:

```
In SWRevealViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad{

 [super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userSignedInSuccessfully) name:kUserSignedInNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userSignOutSuccessfully) name:kUserSignedOutNotification object:nil];

  // this flag should be maintained in user defaults
  if(iSUserSignedIn){

     //Show Home page if user is already signed in
     [self showHomeScreen];
  }
}

#pragma mark - Show Home screen

-(void)showHomeScreen
{
  UINavigationController *navigation = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kStoryboardName bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNavigationController"];

 [self setFrontViewController:navigation];
 [self setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft];
}

-(void)showLoginScreen{

  UINavigationController *navigation = (UINavigationController *)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:kStoryboardName bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavigationController"];

  [self setFrontViewController:navigation];
  [self setFrontViewPosition:FrontViewPositionLeft];
}
```

Now when user signed first save flag **iSUserSignedIn** in user defaults and post this notification.

```
//Post notification for successful sign in
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUserSignedInNotification object:nil];
```

When user signed out set flag **iSUserSignedIn** to nil and post this notification.

```
//Post notification for successful sign out
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kUserSignedOutNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: In the login view, if the user sign in successfully should I write the segue programmatically? Which view should be instantiate after the login succeed? the mene or the homeview? I really appreciate your answer!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry I figured that I can have (showHomeScreen) method after the login succeed.

Comment: it did not move to the login view until I change the way the home view instantiate inside (showHomeScreen) method ----- here is how:  UIViewController *vcNew = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    
    // Swap out the Front view controller and display
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:vcNew];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];